# Issue with Manifest Permission in Android Studio

Tags: android, eclipse, permissions, android-studio, android-manifest

I am new to Android Studio but have enough experience in Android using Eclipse..
This is not a question but weird thing happened with me in Android Studio.
So I want to ask that.

My App is working without any Permissions in Genymotion Emulator. Let me explain.
I have MAC, Working on Andoid Studio from 10 to 15 days, I exported my app from Eclipse and Imported in android Studio. I am uses Genymotion Emulator to check my output..

I used plenty of web-service which is made in PHP in my App. I haven't even declare any permission line in my manifest file still I can use internet services.. WHY???????

It will looks really stupid but believe me, I faced it today. I have spend 1 month in the project and I implemented all the services and today 1 error occured about permission required. I checked menifest and there is no permission declared. Does this happen to anyone else??

Does Google removed Permission declaration in Android Studio?? Is there any other manifest files?? 
I am very shocked. So I might sound stupid now but Please let me know does any one find this problem>? 
It is still working without permission sometimes..

Answer (score 0):

As Android or  eclipse don't touch your AndroidManifest.XML, your problem may come from something else.

To call a web service using internet, you need to add this permission to your app.

The real problem, I think, is not that your app doesn't work without permission but how it can work without

Just add the missing permission to fix your problem.

Comment: If I add permission or don't add, still app works. I have no problem but that is bug.